# Ler inputstream criada em outra activity

Tags: java, android

Sou novato em programação.
Salvei um array de strings através do `FileOutputStream.write()` na minha `MainActivity`.
Consigo ler o *array* perfeitamente através do `FileInputStream` na própria Activity.
Para ler esse *array* em outra Activity utilizei o seguinte código:

```
// READ
FileInputStream fin;
fin = openFileInput("my_file");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
String[] temp = (String[]) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
String texto = temp[5].replace("-", " ");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a2);
tv.setText(texto);
```

O Eclipse apontou o seguinte erro:

> The method openFileInput(String) is undefined for the type AdapterPages

Então fiz a seguinte modificação no código (talvez aí esteja o erro):

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
Context contexto = main.getApplicationContext();
FileInputStream fin;
fin = contexto.openFileInput("my_file");
```

Funciona "sem erros", mas o texto do `TextView tv` não muda.

---

**UPDATE 1**
Salvar o *array*:

```
// WRITE NEW FILE
FileOutputStream fout = openFileOutput("my_file",
        Context.MODE_APPEND);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
oos.writeObject(mVal);
oos.close();
```

**UPDATE 2**
Chamar a outra *activity*:

```
// RU call button
public void btTela1(View v) {
startActivity(new Intent(this, Pager.class).putExtra("dados", texto));
}
```

Comment: como você está fazendo para usar o `FileOutputStream`? Poderia postar esse trecho do código?

Comment: postei... mas creio que o problema não está nele porque conforme eu disse na MainActivity eu leio os dados, mas na outra não

Comment: Felipe, minha sugestão seria dar close no FileOutputStream/FileInputStream também. Olhando a documentação, essas funções dão acesso a leitura/escrita para a aplicação, logo todas as Activities deveriam enchegar o arquivo... Chegou a debugar o retorno da leitura?

Comment: O input e output estão com o close conforme o código q eu postei... Eu rodei no emulador né, nem sabia pra que serve o debug, acabei de pesquisar parece que ele aponta também as variáveis e os valores dela, nao e isso ? vou dar uma estudada no debug até amanhã e posto o resultado dele aqui... Mas vou deixar essa pergunta em aberto, pode ser ? obrigado

Comment: @Wakim acho que não estou sabendo debugar o que você pediu... O debug mostra os valores de variáveis, como String não é variável, não consigo ver o valor do texto que obtenho. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Com breakpoint da pra ver o valor do array, só mudar a perspectiva pra debug. Pelo que li não é preciso fechar todos os stream's, só o ultimo que foi criado em cascata. Outra sugestão seria apagar o arquivo e criar do zero sempre que for escrever um array. Porque você esta abrindo o arquivo em modo `APPEND`, isso é, esta escrevendo sempre no final e o primeiro array escrito pode estar vazio ou com valor antigo. Isso vai depender da sua lógica.

Comment: Outra coisa que me veio a cabeça, está usando esse arquivo apenas para passar dados de uma `Activity` para outra?

Comment: @Wakim na `MainActivity` eu consigo ver o conteudo do *array* com o *debug*, já na outra *activity* não. Fechei o *stream* só no final como você falou. Antes de começar a escrever o *array* eu sempre deleto o arquivo pelo fato de ser `APPEND`. E sim, só quero passar dados de uma *activity* para outra.

Comment: Vou fazer um teste aqui, mas ja que deleta o arquivo eu não vejo erro no código. Mas se é só pra passar dados de uma Activity para outra, é maia recomendado usar como extra do Intent do que arquivo. Aqui no SO pt tem algumas perguntas sobre isso, é bem simples.

Comment: @Wakim pois é, seria bem mais simples, mas eu estou usando um *ViewPager*, aí eu nem imagino como uso *Intent* nesse caso

Comment: Como está iniciando a outra `Activity`?

Comment: @Wakim acrescentei o código

Comment: Felipe, você já está passando **extras**, basta só adicionar o array também.

Comment: @Wakim acho que entendi, mas o problema é na hora de receber. Eu chamo a classe *Pager.class*, mas os *layouts* não são inflados nela, ela só faz o `setAdapter(adapter)`. Ou seja, muito complicado (pra mim). Estou tentanto aqui de várias formas, quando conseguir posto a resposta. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MINHA SOLUÇÃO**
Como havia dito nos comentários da pergunta, o problema principal era ler um `FileInputStream` numa classe que não realiza `extends Activity`. Não era possível obter o **contexto** e então dava erro. Até achei várias soluções para conseguir o **contexto**, mas talvez pelo fato dessa classe ser um `PagerAdapter`, complicava um pouco e não funcionava.

Meu objetivo final era alterar dados numa `TextView` de um *layout* inflado nessa classe.

A partir da resposta de uma pergunta numa situação quase idêntica à minha, foi possível resolver o problema.

Fiz algumas alterações na estrutura do `ViewPager` e então consegui modificar o `TextView` que quero na classe que seta o `PagerAdapter`, a qual realiza `extends Activity`. Portanto agora, por possuir o **contexto**, consigo tanto ler o `FileInputStream` quanto passar dados por `Intent`.

A pergunta e a resposta que utilizei esclarecem melhor o que estou tentando explicar:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/21894580/4407308